# MySQL - how to fix function creation error 1418

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, aggregate-functions, sql-function

Im using mysqlWorkbench

I have followed example work supplied by my tutor and suggestions from other users on this sight but  am now recieving a 1418 error when trying to create the function, as shown in the following:

> Error Code: 1418. This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)    0.00069 sec

The function is as follows:

```
DELIMITER £
CREATE FUNCTION Calc(ReferenceNumber INTEGER)
RETURNS INTEGER

BEGIN 
DECLARE NUMCATS INTEGER;
    SELECT SUM(BOOKCAT.Ref = ReferenceNumber) INTO NUMCATS
    FROM CATTERY.BOOKCAT;
    RETURN NUMCATS;
END £
DELIMITER ;

select calc(7);
```

Let me know what i am doing wrong and how to correct it, thanks.

Comment: How/what ide are you using to create? I would probably avoid using £ as a delimiter

Answer (score 1):

The error message is clear enough. You need to add one of the mentionned keywords in the function definition to make it valid.

Consider:

```
DELIMITER £
CREATE FUNCTION Calc(ReferenceNumber INTEGER)
RETURNS INTEGER
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
DECLARE NUMCATS INTEGER;
    SELECT SUM(BOOKCAT.Ref = ReferenceNumber) INTO NUMCATS
    FROM CATTERY.BOOKCAT;
    RETURN NUMCATS;
END £
DELIMITER ;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dpW5rEWcXQzbev1cPfDLF7/0)**